# Picking words after dash in regex

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have the following text:

```
test = '\n\nDisclaimer ...........................\t10\n\nITOM - IT Object Model ...............\t11\n\nDB – Datenbank Model..................\t11\n\nDB - Datenbank Model - Views .........\t12'
```

which looks like:

```
Disclaimer ...........................  10

ITOM - IT Object Model ...............  11

DB – Datenbank Model..................  11

DB - Datenbank Model - Views .........  12
```

I want to make a list of the contents such that I get:

```
['Disclaimer', 'ITOM - IT Object Model', 'DB – Datenbank Model', 'DB - Datenbank Model - Views' ]
```

so I do the following:

```
re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z\%\$\#\@\!\-\_]\S*', test1, re.MULTILINE)
```

which returns:

```
['Disclaimer', 'ITOM', 'DB', 'DB']
```

I wonder why my RegEx doesn't pick the words after `-`?

Comment: Because you match `\S*` which is a short for *non whitespace*. How about using something different like [`^.*?(?=\s*\.\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/XiF5sS/1). Just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex and a non-regex approach here:

```py
[line.split('...')[0].strip() for line in test1.splitlines() if line.strip()]
[re.sub(r'\s*\.+\s*\d+\s*$', '', line) for line in test1.splitlines() if line.strip()]
re.findall(r'^(.*?)[^\S\n]*\.+[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n]*$', test1, re.M)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/26l4dE).

Notes:

- The text is split into separate lines
- Drop the line if it is blank
- Either split the line with triple dots and get the first chunk
- Or, if you prefer regex, remove the dots followed with optional whitespace, then digits and possibly trailing whitespaces.

Or, if you prefer the fully-regex approach (see the third line of code in the above snippet), you can use `re.findall` with a  `^(.*?)[^\S\n]*\.+[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n]*$` pattern:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\.+` - one or more dots
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `$` - end of line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/onxk2P/1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm proposing an alternate approach, with a different regex.
Replace the unwanted characters, instead of finding the needed ones, as it seems easy for your case.

See below:

```
contents = re.sub(r"\s?(\.)+\s+(\d)+\b", "", text, re.MULTILINE).splitlines(keepends=False)
```

This will produce a list of contents you want.